# How to fix Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connectdb()

Tags: php

I am new for PHP and MYSQL. I have tried some learnings using xampp. when I try to connect database with the script it shows below error..  this showing on index.php

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connectdb() (previously declared in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\core.php:18) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\core.php on line 24

I have a search on google and try to fix this. but it's not worked...
core.php line 18th to 24 th codes as follows.

```
function connectdb()
{
    global $dbname, $dbuser, $dbhost, $dbpass;`
   $conms = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass); //connect mysql`
   if(!$conms) return false;`
   $condb = @mysql_select_db($dbname);`
   if(!$condb) return false;`
   return true;`
}
```

config.php codes as follows

```
$dbname = "aw"; //change to your mysql database name
$dbhost = "localhost"; //database host name
$dbuser = "sam";
$dbpass = "1234";


$max_buds=100; //maximum number of buds
$topic_af = 120; //topic antiflood
$post_af = 45; //post antiflood
$onver = true; //isonline versoion

$timeadjust = (0 * 60 * 60); // 4 hours
putenv("TZ=Africa/Johannesburg");
```

Comment: Please include the code as text in your question and not as an image.

Comment: Please show your config.php file

Comment: Please check. i have add the codes

Comment: Have you tried to change **connectDb()** name into another?

Comment: when it change its show Fatal error: 'Call to undefined function connectdb() in C:\xampp1\htdocs\index.php on line 20 this error'..

Comment: The mysql_*() functions were deprecated over a decade ago and are now removed from the latest php versions. You really should use pdo or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "include guard":

```
if(!function_exists('connectdb')) {
    function connectdb() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue that connectdb function already loaded.

Try use include_once instead of include.
example:

```
include_once 'Functions.php';
```

The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns TRUE. As the name suggests, the file will be included just once.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your **connectdb function** with the following code:

```
if (!function_exists('connectdb')) {
    function connectdb()
    {
        global $dbname, $dbuser, $dbhost, $dbpass;

        $conms = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass); //connect mysql
        if (!$conms) return false;
        $condb = @mysql_select_db($dbname);
        if (!$condb) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

It will only create the function if it does not exist.

Comment: You might solved his problem, but not correctly. I assume the problem is because the file is included multiple times. The issue with non-existent mysql_* functions should be addressed in your answer too as well as the use of silence operator. All of this is a reason I down voted.